# How to remove the Finder menu bar when in fullscreen?

Tags: finder, fullscreen

Trying to use an application in fullscreen mode, but if I move the pointer just a *little* too far when trying to select things at the top of the display the menu bar drops down instead.

Is there a way to disable this, either in per-app settings or from a particular monitor/display?

Using OS X 10.10.x

Comment: ctrl+fn+F2 (you need the fn if your F keys are not enabled)

Comment: @Buscar웃 - thanks, but that looks like it makes the bar appear permanently. Is there a way to disable the mouseover to drop down the menu?

Comment: No, you cannot disable the menu bar appearing.